# Disable and enable gijgo datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using datepicker from gijgo 1.9.14.
I would like to know how to disable and enable it from javascript

```
$("#startDate").datepicker(
    { 
        calendarWeeks: true, 
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4', 
        locale: 'pt-br',
        value : '<?=date('d/m/Y')?>',
        format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
        iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    }
);
```

When I try

```
$("#startDate").prop('disabled',true)
```

The calendar icon is still active, so the user can use it to input data. Cant find anything on the official documentation to explain how to enabe/disable the control.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

found a way, not the prettiest one but it works...

```
//create datepicker
    $('#startDate').datepicker(
        { 
            calendarWeeks: true, 
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4', 
            locale: 'pt-br',
            value : '<?=date('d/m/Y')?>',
            format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
            iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
        }
    );
```

Now with this function

```
        function toggle_calendar( calendar , status )
        {
            let cal = $("#" + calendar);
            let cal_icon = $(cal).next('span').children('button');
            if (status == 'off' )
            {
                $(cal).prop('disabled', true);
                $(cal_icon).prop('disabled', true);
            }
            else
            {
                $(cal).prop('disabled', false);
                $(cal_icon).prop('disabled', false);             
            }
        }
```

We can enable or disable the datepicker by

```
//to disable 
toggle_calendar('startDate', 'off')
//to enable
toggle_calendar('startDate', 'on')
```

Comment: I had to use `let cal_icon = $(cal).next('button');'

Answer (score 0):

I added a new feature request for that in https://github.com/atatanasov/gijgo/issues/719